# readlines() truncating my input string in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I prepared a python script to automate my DB task. I am collecting information about by servers in files(1 per server) and reading each file with readlines() . Everything works fine except for a lengthy string that is getting truncated because of which my if condition is always returning false.

```
("agent","root     123321 123306  0  2019 ?        00:53:36 agent(mysql)")
```

Thats the tuple supposed to be validated , but in my case readlines() has truncated the last part of it

```
("agent","root     123321 123306  0  2019 ?        00:53:36 ")
```

Because of this my if condition which checks if the mysql monitoring agent is running is returning false.

Does readlines() has any limitation in terms of number of characters or am i missing something else?

Thanks

Comment: no there's no limitation. But maybe a newline character slipped into the data?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : i am striping the new line character while forming a tuple tuple((line.rstrip("\n")).split(':')) . I got d issue now.  when i am forming a tuple, whole line is not taken as a single string                                                                                                 ('agent ', ' root      28420  28418  0 12', '40 pts/3    00', '00', '00 agent(mysql)') Instead tuple function breaks it into 4 items.. not sure how i can overcome this problem though. For now i can adjust my validation to pass through since i know the position of the string i am interested.

Comment: best way: dump the raw data and create a [mcve] so we can help you

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre This is input line **agent : root     123321 123306  0  2019 ?        00:53:36 agent(mysql)** to **tuple((line.rstrip("\n")).split(':'))** and the output i am expecting is **("agent","root     28420 28420  0  2019 ?        00:53:36 agent(mysql)")**. But output i am getting is **('agent ', ' root 28420 28418 0 12', '40 pts/3 00', '00', '00 agent(mysql)')** . If i can solve this my issue is solved